# Bootstrap carousel component controls are not transparent

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use a [Bootstrap carousel component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/). The only problem I'm having is that the controls are not transparent, as they are in the example in the bootstrap documentation.

Code below:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="slide-show" data-bs-ride="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="slide-show-contents">
        <div class="carousel-item" style="width: 435px; height: 245px">
            <div>This is a slide</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="width: 435px; height: 245px">
            <div>This is another slide</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button
        class="carousel-control-prev"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#slide-show"
        data-bs-slide="prev"
    >
        <span
            class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"
        ></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button
        class="carousel-control-next"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#slide-show"
        data-bs-slide="next"
    >
        <span
            class="carousel-control-next-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"
        ></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a real answer, but the workaround is to use

```
<a role="button">
```

instead of

```
<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a conflicting style that you have applied for the button element for opacity. It might be overriding the .9 opacity of the carousel buttons.